# Finding dead code in Template toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

We have a number of interconnected tt's in our project. Is there a way to find template code which is never used?

At least in theory, I could hack into Template, make it mark control blocks somehow and write usage data to a file for later analysis (much like Devel::Cover does). But maybe there's already a tool for that? I haven't found one though.

Here's a useful [post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2014/07/finding-unused-variables-in-your-template-stash.html) on this topic but not quite what I want.